# Creating Effective dated table by merging two table

Tags: sql

I have one table with start and end date (initial setup) and another table with just effective date with the new changes . I like to merge these two tables with effective dated

Table 1 :

[image]

Comment: Which RDMS are you using ?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by first implementing my `UNI`query. It will merge all dates for emp_ids together then ordering them(in my case with using `LEAD` window function) makes it easy. For `ORACLE` you can use below query.

[Working Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e9142785ffeca87580970f921696cea)

```
WITH EMP
     AS (SELECT 1 AS EMP_ID,
                TO_DATE ('20200101', 'YYYYMMDD') AS START_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('20201231', 'YYYYMMDD') AS END_DATE,
                4500 SALARY,
                'New york' AS location,
                'Software Engineer' title
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS EMP_ID,
                TO_DATE ('20200101', 'YYYYMMDD') AS START_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('20201231', 'YYYYMMDD') AS END_DATE,
                3400 SALARY,
                'seattle' AS location,
                'Software Engineer' title
           FROM DUAL),
     TRANSFER
     AS (SELECT 1 AS EMP_ID,
                TO_DATE ('20200501', 'YYYYMMDD') AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
                4800 SALARY,
                'New york'LOCATION,
                'Software Engineer' title
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS EMP_ID,
                TO_DATE ('20200501', 'YYYYMMDD') AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
                3700 SALARY,
                'Seatlle'LOCATION,
                'Software Engineer' title
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS EMP_ID,
                TO_DATE ('20200701', 'YYYYMMDD') AS EFFECTIVE_DATE,
                4000 SALARY,
                'Seattle'LOCATION,
                'Sr.Software Engineer' title
           FROM DUAL),
     UNI
     AS (SELECT EMP_ID, START_DATE DATEE FROM EMP
         UNION
         SELECT EMP_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE FROM TRANSFER
         UNION
         SELECT EMP_ID, END_DATE FROM EMP),
     MAIN
     AS (SELECT A.EMP_ID,
                DATEE AS START_DATE,
                CASE WHEN FF != MDATE THEN LEAD(DATEE,1)OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATEE) - 1 ELSE MDATE END END_DATE
           FROM (SELECT EMP_ID,
                        DATEE,
                        LEAD (DATEE, 1)
                           OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATEE)
                           FF,
                        MAX (DATEE) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID) AS MDATE
                   FROM UNI) A
          WHERE FF IS NOT NULL)
SELECT MAIN.EMP_ID,
       MAIN.START_DATE,
       MAIN.END_DATE,
       NVL(EMP.SALARY,TRANSFER.SALARY) SALARY,
       NVL(EMP.LOCATION,TRANSFER.LOCATION)LOCATION,
       NVL(EMP.TITLE,TRANSFER.TITLE) TITLE
  FROM MAIN LEFT JOIN EMP ON EMP.EMP_ID = MAIN.EMP_ID AND EMP.START_DATE=MAIN.START_DATE
  LEFT JOIN TRANSFER ON TRANSFER.EMP_ID = MAIN.EMP_ID AND TRANSFER.EFFECTIVE_DATE=MAIN.START_DATE
  ORDER BY 1,2
```

[image]